Can the Yang-Mills-Higgs equations be simplified?
Let $G$ be a compact Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and $E\twoheadrightarrow B$ be a principal $G$-bundle over a compact orientable Riemannian manifold $B$. For a connection $A\in\Omega_{\mathrm{Ad}}^1(E,\mathfrak{g})\cong\Omega^1(B,\operatorname{Ad}(E))$ and a section $\Phi\in\Omega_{\mathrm{Ad}}^0(E,\mathfrak{g})\cong\Omega^0(B,\operatorname{Ad}(E))\cong\Gamma^\infty(B,\operatorname{Ad}(E))$, the Yang-Mills-Higgs equations* are:
$$
\mathrm{d}_A\star F_A
+\star[\Phi,\mathrm{d}_A\Phi]
=0;
$$
$$
\mathrm{d}_A\star\mathrm{d}_A\Phi
=0.
$$
Using the adjoint operator $\mathrm{d}_A^*=\pm\star\mathrm{d}_A\star$, the second equation can be rewritten as $\mathrm{d}_A^*\mathrm{d}_A\Phi=0$. But then one can employ the following old trick from Hodge theory:
$$
\|\mathrm{d}_A\Phi\|^2
=\langle\mathrm{d}_A\Phi,\mathrm{d}_A\Phi\rangle
=\langle\Phi,\mathrm{d}_A^*\mathrm{d}_A\Phi\rangle
=0
$$
to conclude $\mathrm{d}_A\Phi=0$. But this would reduce the first equation to just the Yang-Mills equations $\mathrm{d}_A\star F_A=0$, which seems suspicious. What exactly doesn't work out here? I'm pretty sure, that the reason is the Lie algebra, since the equation with the scalar products above takes values in $\mathfrak{g}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$, but I'm not sure how exactly? Does the step $\|\mathrm{d}_A\Phi\|^2=0\Rightarrow\mathrm{d}_A\Phi=0$ become wrong?
General remarks on the scalar product of Lie algebra valued differential forms could also help. If $\mathfrak{g}$ has a basis of vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n\in\mathfrak{g}$ and $(\omega_i)_{1\leq i\leq n},(\eta_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}\in\Omega^k(B)$ are differential forms, I think it is:
$$
\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_i\otimes v_i,\sum_{j=1}^n\eta_j\otimes v_j\right\rangle
=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle\omega_i,\eta_i\rangle\otimes v_i.
$$
I've found no reference so far though, so those would also be welcome of course.
(* In On the Yang-Mills-Higgs equations by Clifford Henry Taubes from 1984, they are missing a Hodge star operator. His works from 1982 or 1985 contain the correct Yang-Mills-Higgs equations though.)

(I was pretty surprised, that there is no hashtag "yang-mills" like on Physics Stackexchange. Since there are 165 results for "Yang-Mills", I've started one. If it's not necessary, have my blessing to remove it.)

@JesseMadnick Also on non-compact manifolds, for example the linked works by Clifford Henry Taubes do so on three-dimensional euclidean space. It's actually the property for which I don't understand, why it's additionally assumed so often. Compactness of Lie groups because of the Milnor construction of classifying spaces and orientability of the base manifold because of the fundamental class. Makes sense! But its compactness seems unnecessary for me so far, although it's often additionally assumed as well.

My question was meant as: Are the YMH equations ever studied on compact manifolds?  Because it could be the case that your calculation -- which seems to use the compactness of the base -- is correct, and shows that the YMH equations aren't interesting in the compact setting.  (Again, I'm not an expert; I'm just speculating.)

@JesseMadnick Ah, I see! I myself don't need compactness and rethinking again, it's actually the Yang-Mills equations for which it is often additionally assumed. A quick search through some papers I've read and it's indeed not assumed for the Yang-Mills-Higgs equations anywhere. So you could be right. I've also been told that if the manifold being closed is probably central due to boundary terms arising when integrating the scalar product.

Your attempt at a scalar product is far from a scalar product. The wedge product of $\mathfrak g$-valued forms is defined using the Lie bracket structure. You certainly will need an inner product on $\mathfrak g$ (typically related to the Killing form in the semisimple case) and then you should expand by bilinearity, as usual. It would be more convenient to use an orthonormal basis for $\mathfrak g$.
